# The best way to filter a huge collection?

Tags: c#

I can't come up with a solution to filter a huge (30,000+ items) collection in a very performant way...

Here is the case I have:
We have a scene with scene objects. I serialize these scene objects to a collection. Every scene object is represented as an instance of SceneObject class which includes data about object's poisition in scene, its rotation etc. All of these objects can have positions in range from (-1000, -1000) to (1000, 1000) coordinates.
We should be able to get a list of objects that have position in a range of coordinates. For example we need to get a list of objects that have positions in range from (150, -800) to (250, -600).

The problem is that the operation of getting results should be very performant and shouldn't allocate any garbage. I could think of indexing this list once but I can't undetstand how to make it correctly.

So what is the best way to do it?

Here is how I do it now. I stored all objects in SQLite database table and query needed objects with SELECT query, but the performance of such approach is slow and it allocated garbage:

```
List<SceneObjectData> objectsToStream;

void LoadSceneObjectsAroundPlayer()
{
    objectsToStream = dbManager.Query<SceneObjectData>(BuildSqlQuery());
    
    foreach (SceneObjectData sceneObjectData in objectsToStream)
    {
        LoadObject(sceneObjectData);
    }
}

string BuildSqlQuery()
        {
            query = "SELECT * FROM SceneObjectData" +
                                " WHERE " + "((objectsSizeType = " + (int)SceneObjectSize.huge +
                                " AND " + "xPosition > " + (tempPosition.x - hugeObjectsRadius).ToString() +
                                " AND " + "xPosition < " + (tempPosition.x + hugeObjectsRadius).ToString() +
                                " AND " + "zPosition > " + (tempPosition.z - hugeObjectsRadius).ToString() +
                                " AND " + "zPosition < " + (tempPosition.z + hugeObjectsRadius).ToString() + ")" +
                                " OR " + "(objectsSizeType = " + (int)SceneObjectSize.big +
                                " AND " + "xPosition > " + (tempPosition.x - bigObjectsRadius).ToString() +
                                " AND " + "xPosition < " + (tempPosition.x + bigObjectsRadius).ToString() +
                                " AND " + "zPosition > " + (tempPosition.z - bigObjectsRadius).ToString() +
                                " AND " + "zPosition < " + (tempPosition.z + bigObjectsRadius).ToString() + ")" +
                                " OR " + "(objectsSizeType = " + (int)SceneObjectSize.medium +
                                " AND " + "xPosition > " + (tempPosition.x - mediumObjectsRadius).ToString() +
                                " AND " + "xPosition < " + (tempPosition.x + mediumObjectsRadius).ToString() +
                                " AND " + "zPosition > " + (tempPosition.z - mediumObjectsRadius).ToString() +
                                " AND " + "zPosition < " + (tempPosition.z + mediumObjectsRadius).ToString() + ")" +
                                " OR " + "(objectsSizeType = " + (int)SceneObjectSize.small +
                                " AND " + "xPosition > " + (tempPosition.x - smallObjectsRadius).ToString() +
                                " AND " + "xPosition < " + (tempPosition.x + smallObjectsRadius).ToString() +
                                " AND " + "zPosition > " + (tempPosition.z - smallObjectsRadius).ToString() +
                                " AND " + "zPosition < " + (tempPosition.z + smallObjectsRadius).ToString() + "))" +
                                " AND isLoaded = 0";

            query = query.Replace(",", ".");

            return query;
        }
```

I would very appreciate any suggestion or advice!

Comment: Where is the data stored. Is it in a database?

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil. How long does your current way take? How long is acceptable? Ask yourself these 2 questions and you'll worry about performance 90% less.

Comment: Have you tried to make LINQ query ?

Comment: @PeterSmith now it's stored in SQLite table, but querying results creating a lot of garbage so I guess it's not the best solution...

Comment: 30k items is not huge; honestly, that's pretty modest (the system you're using right now constantly filters 21M items in memory). However, for a geometric lookup, the first thing I'd look at would be indexing the items into chunks - for example, cutting your available coordinates into a 10x10 grid; now you can very quickly scan just the relevant boxes

Comment: Writing a query to select only the objects you're looking for would create significantly less garbage than holding all of the objects in memory and iterating through them. Can you clarify why you believe this "results creating a lot of garbage"?

Comment: List<Obj> Rang01;// ( 0 ,0 ) ~ ( 100 , 100 )
List<Obj> Rang02;// ( 201 ,100 ) ~ ( 300 , 100 )
create like this , and search some list enough

Comment: @Llama that is hugely contextual; it can *absolutely* be more efficient to query in memory, *as long as* you do it sensibly and don't constantly fetch all the data *and* you know how to sensibly filter

Comment: @ThomasWeller now it takes from 20 to 40ms as Unity game enigne shows. It should be no more than 5ms. Optimization is a very important in this aspect because I'm loading the list of objects in a real time game 1-2 times in second.

Comment: @Philippe it allocates a lot of garbage in my test unfortunately

Comment: You're talking about garbage often. How do you measure garbage?

Comment: @IvanPetrov since you haven't shown *how* you're querying this data, it is impossible for us to comment about garbage, however: I can say categorically that doing a `foreach` over a `List<T>` applying an `if(...)` inside the loop: won't allocate (`List<T>` has a custom value-type enumerator, and the compiler doesn't generate a capture context for `if`). If you're doing something different, you need to **show some code**

Comment: Can I suggest that you a) provide a concrete definition for what you consider to be garbage, b) provide an example for how you're currently filtering this information currently, c) if you have an example of how you queried it from the database, please also provide that.

Comment: @MarcGravell thank you, I thought about this solution too. I'll try it if there is no another solution! :)

Comment: As for garbage - Unity engine profiler shows that the method where I querying results allocates it. It's critical because when garbage is alloccated and GC collector collects it, the game freezes because it happens on a main thread.

Comment: I just wanted to add: if you have all of this in memory, the usual way to filter the objects by 2d position would probably be to use something like a quadtree. There will be a performance penalty when assembling the tree, but you can evaluate it quickly.

Comment: @MarcGravell I'll update the question to show code, but there is almost nothing to show - just a simple SELECT sql query. Iterating won't allocate garbage but it's slow

Comment: @IvanPetrov if you're doing a `SELECT` query, you're presumably looking in a database; a database is not a "collection", and isn't "instances" etc. It would *really* help to have code, because we're already talking about 2 **completely** different scenarios.

Comment: ok; what is generating data here is that horrible SELECT code; firstly, *use parameters* (it *looks* like you might be using Dapper here, in which case, parameters should be trivial); secondly: 30k is tiny - just load the data once into a `List<SceneObject>` or similar (perhaps update it periodically for changes), and just **filter in memory with `foreach`**

Comment: @MarcGravell thank you that you are trying to help! You asked how I do it now and that's how I'm doing it. As my tests demonstrate me, It's a wrong approach and I thought that I don't need to mention it. I wanted to ask about the best approaches for it.

Comment: @MarcGravell I'll try to use foreach, thanks! I thought that it's heavy to perform foreach through 30k items every second...

Comment: @IvanPetrov no; even before doing any work (such as where I suggested splitting the data into chunks based on a grid), in my local test it takes 0.26ms to scan 30k items based on `double` X/Y in a range, with zero allocations. Splitting it into chunks could make it *in the best case* take 1% of that time.

Comment: As a side note: since out-of-process is a consideration, you could also consider using databases *designed for geospatial search*; Redis has geospatial support, for example, although it is lat-long (globe) based. I suspect other geospatial database systems exist with a range of coordinate systems that would allow effective search. But: going out-of-process is almost always slower than querying in memory *if* you can fit the data in local memory *and* you can devise effective filter mechanisms without needing specialist knowledge against a dedicated expert-written indexing system.

Comment: @MarcGravell oh, I didn't know that there are databases designed for such needs! Thanks, it's very helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is surprisingly expensive to construct a SQL query (even with static text), add parameters in ADO.NET, send it over the wire, collect the results, and materialize that into an object model. Fine for discreet operations, or line-of-business apps, but *not* good for constantly working with the same data. For *that*, it would be better to *load the data once* into an in-memory model, and *work in local memory*. By any objective measure, 30k objects is *tiny* and you shouldn't really need to optimize it, but if this number was order(s) of magnitude higher, you could get more advanced by breaking your coordinate system into smaller grids, keeping each chunk separately, so you can very quickly omit entire chunks (and everything they contain), only actually scanning the chunks that overlap your query range.

In a simple test here, it seems to take about .25ms locally to scan 30k items based on a `double` X/Y range, the naïve way:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;

class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var list = new List<SceneItem>();
        var rand = new Random();
        for(int i = 0; i < 30_000; i++)
        {
            list.Add(new SceneItem {
                X = (rand.NextDouble() * 2000) - 1000,
                Y = (rand.NextDouble() * 2000) - 1000 }
            );
        }
        Console.WriteLine(CountItems(list, 100, -800, 250, -600));
        var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            CountItems(list, 100, -800, 250, -600);
        }
        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds); // note: benchmark.net would be better here

        static int CountItems(List<SceneItem> items, double fromX, double fromY, double toX, double toY)
        {
            int count = 0;
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                if (item.X >= fromX && item.Y >= fromY && item.X < toX && item.Y < toY)
                    count++;
            }
            return count;
        }
    }
}

public class SceneItem
{
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
}
```

Note also: avoid switching to LINQ here; anything that involves a capture context (so: lambdas, query expressions, etc) and delegate/expression trees, is going to create lots of allocations. It is also very deliberate that I'm using a simple container type; `List<T>` and arrays like `T[]` can be iterated without allocations; abstractions like `IList<T>`, `IEnumerable<T>` etc **cannot**.

Note that if you need to update an in-memory model from a database, you can use tricks like `CHECKSUM_AGG` to check whether there are likely changes, *without* having to fetch everything each time.

Comment: I've just tested it myself and it really works very good! The interesting thing is that I haven't event tested a simple iterating through this collection because I was sure that it's very slow... Thank you for your answer Marc Gravell! :)

Comment: @IvanPetrov slow is relative; computers are *incredibly good* at performing memory tests in local memory; sure, scanning is slower than (for example) doing a dictionary-lookup based on a key, but that doesn't make it "slooooooow" - just slower. And as I tried to emphasize: there are things you can do even if the volume is higher; chunking, for example, or scanning the space in parallel using multiple threads, or building secondary indexing for high-usage scenarios

Comment: One note here.. the question query code shows 4 types of scenery objects in the list. For each type, there is a different radius (distance) test. Suppose you'd have 1e6 objects instead of 30k, it could help to use Gravell's proposal to read these 4 separate lists into memory and filter/sort into 4 separate sets. It will yield smaller lists and It will also simplify the condition test and speed things up further.